# Undoing a git config command when I can't find the output target

Tags: git

I ran `git config credential.helper --help` and now whenever I push the first line is `git: 'credential---help' is not a git command.` But I can't find where that command wrote to. My .gitconfig file doesn't have it. I don't have an /etc/gitconfig. Where else can I look?

Comment: Try `git config --show-origin credential.helper`. If your git is too old to support `--show-origin`, search `.git/config`, `~/.gitconfig`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `cd` into that same directory where you were when you gave the faulty command. Then say

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

Like magic, your question will be answered. You will see every configuration setting *and where it lives*.

Comment: Nope. That just lists the lines from my .gitconfig which does not include `credential---help` anywhere.

Comment: No, but it will list `credential.helper`.

Comment: That's true. It shows the correct setting of  `credential.helper=store`.

Comment: Did you `cd` into the same place you were when you gave the faulty command to begin with?

Comment: I'll add that to the answer just in case! Kinda crucial.